# ClearShipoutPicture for next page?

Tags: backgrounds, page, eso-pic, shipout

I've managed to use `eso-pic` + `calc` packages in order to draw a vertical line on the right margin between a "begin" and an "end" statement.

I made this for manuscript review in order to ease reading and commenting tasks for my thesis supervisors : the line is drawn between `\NEW` and `\ENDNEW` in order to make the location of new writings obvious to them.

I'm pretty happy with what I've got right now but there is still one thing that bothers me: **the line is missing the last page!**

---

**In my preambule:**

```latex
\usepackage{eso-pic,calc}
\newlength{\rightrule}
\setlength{\rightrule}{4\leftmargin+\textwidth+\marginparsep}

\newcommand{\MarginLineNew}{\AddToShipoutPicture{%
   \AtPageLowerLeft{%
     \put(\LenToUnit{\rightrule},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}  % Rule on the right
   }
}}

%start label for new stuff
\newcommand{\NEW}{\MarginLineNew}

%end label for new stuff
\newcommand{\ENDNEW}{\ClearShipoutPicture{}}
```

---

**In the document:**

```latex
[...]
Some text
[...]
\NEW

Some text
[...]

\ENDNEW
```

Obviously, calling `\ENDNEW` sets the current page with `\ClearShipoutPicture` while I'd need it to apply on the next page, but I don't know how if it's possible to refer to page +1 with this function.

Any ideas with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to add a hook for the current page only after you clear the shipout picture, using the starred version `\AddToShipoutPicture*`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic,calc}
\newlength{\rightrule}
\setlength{\rightrule}{6\leftmargin+\textwidth+\marginparsep}

\newcommand{\MarginLineNew}{\AddToShipoutPicture{%
   \AtPageLowerLeft{%
     \put(\LenToUnit{\rightrule},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}  % Rule on the right
   }
}}
\newcommand{\MarginLineCurrent}{\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
   \AtPageLowerLeft{%
     \put(\LenToUnit{\rightrule},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}  % Rule on the right
   }
}}

%start label for new stuff
\newcommand{\NEW}{\MarginLineNew}

%end label for new stuff
\newcommand{\ENDNEW}{\ClearShipoutPicture\MarginLineCurrent}

\begin{document}
\NEW
\section{new part}
\lipsum[1-6]
\ENDNEW
\section{old part}
\lipsum[6-20]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much ! :-)